# commutator of $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a non-commutative $C^*$ algebra,can we  define $[A,A]$ as the ideal generated by the set $\{xy-yx:x,y\in A\}$such that $A/[A,A]$ is commutative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, $A/[A,A]$ is always commutative.  Let $\pi:A\to A/[A,A]$ be the quotient map.  If $x,y\in A/[A,A]$, fix $a,b\in A$ such that $\pi(a)=x$, $\pi(b)=y$.  Then $[x,y]=\pi([a,b])=0$, since $[a,b]\in [A,A]$.

But it may well happen that $[A,A]=A$, and it may not.  For example, if $A=K(H)$ or $B(H)$ for a Hilbert space $H$, then $[A,A]=A$.  But it may not be the whole algebra, as in the case that $A=C([0,1])\oplus M_n(\mathbb C)$ we have $[A,A]=0\oplus M_n(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: You mean "the conclusion is not correct in the 2nd example"?

Comment: No, the conclusion is correct.  Let me add some words.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The conclusion that $[A,A]=A$ for $A$ simple is true, by definition.

Comment: No, a counterexample is given by $B(H)$.

Comment: Does there exist a sufficient and necessary condition for $[A,A]=A$?